# App Engine authentication to access google cloud resources

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-authentication, google-iam

1. I'm building an app using which the users registered(from the IAM page) for the project can access the resources of that project. I need the authentication when the URL is hit. Is there a way to achieve this?
2. Is it possible to provide IAM roles specific for a user request (assuming that the user will login using his email id) to access the resources based on IAM level permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the early days of AppEngine it was pretty easy to do some basic auth/access-control, but lately they're moving it to something called [IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap/).

Answer (score 0):

From your wording I am assuming you are trying to abstract administrative tasks of a GCP project to lesser privileged administrators.

Questions 1 and 2 can be quickly solved by defining privileges in IAM using a pre-built roles or creating a custom role if you need to be more specific. Hereby you can use GSuite, GMail, Google Group accounts and let them sign into *console.cloud.google.com*. They will consequently only be able to see and act upon what you've assigned to them to in IAM.

If you still want to go through with building it yourself, every product does provide an API including authentication. Best practice for your use case is to instead of assigning an individual user access to a resource, you rather create a service account and then allow the user to call that service account. For this GCP has the *Service Account Actor Role* described well [in the official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts) and also Salmaan Rashid provides a [good practical insight on medium](https://medium.com/google-cloud/using-serviceaccountactor-iam-role-for-account-impersonation-on-google-cloud-platform-a9e7118480ed).